# Fruit Transformation

Tags: word-ladder

This word ladder is a little more difficult, especially being 5 letter words.

Can you transform an **APPLE** into a **MANGO**?

No proper names.

 Goal is to be smallest amount of steps.

> Can be done in 12 steps, upwards of 26.

Comment: Could you give a more comprehensive set of rules? Like, how many letters to be changed per turn, can letters be jumbled, etc.?

Comment: @Sid I'm assuming standard rules: each turn consists of changing a single letter, no reordering or adding or removing of letters.

Comment: @Sid Rand is right, I was just assuming based off the normal word-ladder rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**12 Steps**

> APPLE-AMPLE-AMOLE-ANOLE-ANILE-ANISE-ARISE-PRISE-PAISE-MAISE-MANSE-MANGE-MANGO

Comment: Well that was quick... did you use a tool to solve it?

Comment: @n_palum I started backwards with the E at the end giving me mange.. Used litscape and google. A bit of trial and error. If you hadn't added that spoiler, I would have refrain myself from adding it considering it to be a bad attempt:-) Also, there is no as such logic involved here. You need to have a tool like litscape *at least* to get these.Or may be you should be [T-bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_%22T-Bag%22_Bagwell) with an amazing vocab. :-)

Comment: Hmm.. interesting, well that's what I had as my 12 step one :) good job as usual